# Running(Deploying) app extensions without containing app

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios-app-extension

I have written an today extension for the notification center and I would like to deploy and run the app extension without the containing app. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not deploy Extension without containing Application, so you have to deploy your container application to deploy Today Extension.

You can read in detail for Today Extension from this Apple link : [Today Widget](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.